# git lfs prune retaining almost all files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I having a repository with a huge amount of files which are tracked by git-lfs. I pushed them all to my remote via `git lfs push --all <remote>`. Then I tried to decrease my local repository size by pruning the git-lfs objects:

```
> git lfs prune --force
prune: 39598 local objects, 39594 retained, done.
prune: Deleting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
```

However from my 39598 objects 39594 are retained and only 4 are deleted. As far as I understand `git lfs push -all` pushes every file to my remote host. And then `git lfs prune --force` should delete every files which is not pushed (but every file should be pushed?!). Am I misunderstood anything? Are the any option to see which file has been pushed and which file not?